# jQuery change background image to several divs at random intervals

Tags: jquery, background-image, settimeout

I have several divs displayed next to each other on my site, each with a different background image. I have created a script that changes the background images at a random time interval, However, the script changes all the images at the same time....I want each one to change randomly, totally independent of the other....I'd also like them to fade, but the timing is the key question here.

Here is my script I'm working with.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    var images = ['images/gallery/gallery2thumb.jpg','images/gallery/gallery3thumb.jpg','images/gallery/gallery4thumb.jpg','images/gallery/gallery5thumb.jpg','images/gallery/gallery6thumb.jpg','images/gallery/gallery7thumb.jpg','images/gallery/gallery8thumb.jpg','images/gallery/gallery9thumb.jpg',];
    var i = 0;
    var timeoutVar;

    function changeBackground() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutVar); // just to be sure it will run only once at a time

        jQuery('.hexagon-in2.change').css('background-image', function() {
            if (i >= images.length) {
                i=0;
            }
            return 'url(' + images[i++] + ')';      
        });

        timeoutVar = setTimeout(changeBackground, ( 300+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1700) ));
    }

    changeBackground();        
});
```

also see my JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/QwJfn/2/

How can I get each div to change background image at random time intervals but independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
 var images = ['http://www.placekitten.com/250/300','http://www.placekitten.com/260/300','http://www.placekitten.com/260/310'];
 var i = 0;
 var allDivs = [];

 function changeBackground() {
     allDivs = $(".hexagon-in2").each(function(){       
        setBG($(this),1000);
  });      
 }

 function setBG(div, time){
    var timeVar;
    clearTimeout(timeVar);

    if( div == undefined){
       return;   
    }

    div.css('background-image', function() {
       if (i >= images.length) {
           i=0;
       }
      return 'url(' + images[i++] + ')';      
   });

   timeVar = setTimeout(setTimer, time);    
  }

 function getRandomInt (min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
 }

 function setTimer(){
   var imageIndex = getRandomInt(0,allDivs.length);
   setBG($(allDivs[imageIndex]),3000);  
 }

 $(function(){          
    changeBackground();        
 });
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QwJfn/10/

Comment: These images all appear to change at the same time though, which is the issue i'm having already

Comment: @SamSkirrow: buddy i have updated my fiddle and code here check its demo.. i hope it helps now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to register a separate timeout for each `div`.

Alternatively, you could choose a random `div` to change each time and reduce the timeout factor so the function runs more often:

```
function changeBackground() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutVar); // just to be sure it will run only once at a time

    var elements = jQuery('.hexagon-in2.change');
    jQuery(elements[Math.floor(Math.random() * (elements.length + 1))]).css('background-image', function() {
        if (i >= images.length) {
            i=0;
        }
        return 'url(' + images[i++] + ')';      
    });

    timeoutVar = setTimeout(changeBackground, ( 300+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1700) ));
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the script, I added it into my JSfiddle and it didn't seem to do anything though

Comment: @Sam: Whoops, I was a little fast and loose with my random function :) Try the edited version.